# concatenating (adding) two charcter strings

Tags: c, char, concatenation, fgets

I was told to write a program containing a concatenate function. This program should collect the input strings using `fgets (&s1[0], len1+1, stdin)`
and then add the two to each other to produce a final product.

My problem falls in that the program compiles but it doesn't display anything on the screen whatsoever, here's what I've got. I couldn't see how I could get it solved without this method of approach.

```
//function to terminate the program incase reach of 0
int str_len (char s[])
{          
int i=0;
while (s[i]= NULL)
++i;
return i+1;
}
char string_cat (char*s1, char*s2)
{
//ADDING THE TWO STRINGS
int str_len(char s[])
char *s1 [80]= {'\0'};
char *s2 [40]= {'\0'};
int len1=str_len(s1);
int  len2=str_len(s2);
if (int x=0; len1+len2<80; \0;
return;
}
int main ()
{
char string_cat(char*s1,char*s2)
int str_len(char s[])
//RECIVING THE STRINGS TO ADD
char s1 [80];
char s2 [40];
int i=0;
for (i; i !=0; ++i)
{
printf("What is the first sentence?: ")
fgets(*s1[0], 75+1, stdin);
printf("What is the second sentence?:")
fgets(*s2[0],35+1,stdin);
string_cat(*s1,*s2);
printf("The two sentences added together produce the following: %c",s1 )
}
++i
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. When I try to compile it I get a plethora of errors. What did you use to compile it?

Comment: in your main function you are passing variable without declaring it first.

Comment: I used codeblocks. maybe that's why../ edit: I had another program open.. that's why, I got the errors now.. back to the drawing board

Comment: If you want others to read your question, start by editing it and fix the indention.

Answer (score 1):

aside from the mistake with the for loop that others have pointed out, the while loop in your str_len function is wrong.
you should've used while(s[i] != NULL) instead of s[i] = null. one equal sign, "=", is assignment; two equal signs, "==", is comparisons; and exclamation equals, "!=", means not equal.

Secondly, you reassign your s1 and s2 to different memory locations in your string_cat function with their first character as NULL, "\0". this will always give your str_len a length of 0 if corrected your str_len function as pointed out above, and a length of random number if not corrected based on what's occupying your memory at run time.

thirdly [still in the string_cat function], your *if(int x = 0; len1 + len2 < 80; \0;* doesn't make sense. you're not doing any concatenations in this function at all.

Sorry for not providing you with the solution as this is a simple exercise. I feel like spoiling you if I were to provide you with the code.

Answer (score 0):

In your code having lot of compilation error. Copy paste the code what you have compiled.

Check this line of code

```
int i=0;
for (i; i !=0; ++i)
```

Because of this you are not getting any thing. In for loop you have condition  `i !=0` which always fail so it's not entering inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

First problem is here

```
int i=0;
for (i; i !=0; ++i)
```

You set value 0 to the variable `i`, and then you check if it does not equal 0. This check does not obviosly pass because `i` equals `0`.

The second problem is also the loop. I can't really get the reason you need the loop it at all, because `i` is not used at all, exept the increment. So as far as i get it, the loop is not needed at all.

Comment: "The input strings should be collected sequentially from the keyboard using fgets(&s1[0], len1 + 1, stdin)and fgets(&s2[0], len2 + 1, stdin)where, len1 and len2 are the maximum size of the respective input strings"

Comment: Well that clears it a bit. As far as i understand it you do not need the for (i; i !=0; ++i) at all. As i said - it's not used, and it's not needed more to the point